# Multiplication of Two Infinite Series

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

This question has been deleted.

---

How to prove that

$$\displaystyle \left( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty }\frac{\left( -a\right) ^{k}y^{2k}}{k!}\right)
\left( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty }\frac{a^{k}y^{2k+1}}{\left( 2k+1\right) k!}%
\right) =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }\frac{2^{2k}\left( -a\right) ^{k}k!}{\left(
2k+1\right) !}y^{2k+1}$$.

The coefficient of $y^{2k+1}$ can be written as
$$\displaystyle 
\sum_{i=0}^{k}\frac{\left( -a\right) ^{k-i}y^{2\left( k-i\right) }}{\left(
k-i\right) !}\frac{a^{i}y^{2i+1}}{\left( 2i+1\right) i!}
$$
thus, it is remaining to prove that
$$\displaystyle
\sum_{i=0}^{k}\frac{\left( -1\right) ^{i}}{\left( k-i\right) !i!\left(
2i+1\right) }=\frac{2^{2k}k!}{\left( 2k+1\right) !}
$$

Comment: In your first, I would make the dummy variables different.  That way, if you combine the two sums on the left, you can keep track of them more easily.

Comment: This is against the site policy to delete one's own question for no clear reason. Previous version restored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-a)^k y^{2k}}{k!}=e^{-ay^2}.$$
Second,$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{a^k}{k!}\int_{0}^y x^{2k}dx=\int_{0}^y e^{ax^2}dx.$$

The left-hand side is
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^y e^{a(x^2-y^2)}dx \quad (*)
\end{equation}

Then use integral by parts,
$$(*)=y-\int_{0}^y 2a x^2 e^{a(x^2-y^2)} dx = y-\int_{0}^y \frac{2a}{3}  e^{a(x^2-y^2)} dx^3.$$
Repeart this process, it shoud arrive at the right-hand side.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** Look at the ways an odd number can be written as a sum of an even number and another odd number i.e. $$2k+1 = 0 + 2k+1 = 2 + 2k-1 = \cdots = 2k-2 + 3 = 2k +1$$

Comment: Thanks for your hint. But it is just a comment not an answer. Can you edit it so that I can delete this question?